# Fragment onCreateView is never called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I noticed that `onCreateView()` of one of my fragments is never called and i dont know why.I need to be able to make changes in `onResume()` but thats is also never called.

Here is how I add the fragments.

```
public class LiveGameStats extends FragmentActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_game_stats);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.tab1, new Tab1Fragment()).commit();
    }

    FragmentTabHost mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(R.id.liveGameTabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(LiveGameStats.this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.liverealtabcontent);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("You"),
            LiveGameTab1Fragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Your Team"),
            LiveGameTab2Fragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Your Enemies"),
            LiveGameTab3Fragment.class, null);
}
```

Tab1Fragment

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    Log.v("FRAGMENT","FragmentActivityCreateView");
    return V;
}
```

And finnaly the xml passed under `R.layout.tab1`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context=".DeviceFragment" >

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
    android:src="@drawable/waves"
    android:background="@drawable/search_selector"
    android:padding="40dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:onClick="liveMatch"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I think I might have created the fragments the wrong way. As you see it now they are created as the xml says but when I changed tabs, the content is "reseted".Any changed I placed in `onCreateView()` or `onResume()` is not called.

**EDIT**

I have tried to implement the method described in the 1st comment. After the implementation the tabs have the same content. Is like all the tabs have the same content. This time I posted all my classes and their associated XML.

```
public class LiveGameStats extends FragmentActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_game_stats);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.liverealtabcontent, new LiveGameTab1Fragment()).commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.liverealtabcontent, new LiveGameTab2Fragment()).commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.liverealtabcontent, new LiveGameTab3Fragment()).commit();

    }

    FragmentTabHost mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(R.id.liveGameTabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(LiveGameStats.this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.liverealtabcontent);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("You"),
            LiveGameTab1Fragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Your Team"),
            LiveGameTab2Fragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Your Enemies"),
            LiveGameTab3Fragment.class, null);
}
```

activity_live_game_stats.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/activity_live_game_stats"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
  tools:context="lucian.leagueassistant.activity.LiveGameStats">


  <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/liveGameTabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/liverealtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
  </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

I wont post the code from `LiveGameTab2` and `LiveGameTab3` since they are almost the same. I have also another activity that

**Edit2**

Seems its solved when i changed from `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.liverealtabcontent, new LiveGameTab1Fragment()).commit();` to `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.tabcontent, new LiveGameTab1Fragment()).commit();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.tab1, new Tab1Fragment()).commit();
```

In the first argument you have to pass a id to a container in the Activity layout where your fragment will be attached.

You are passing a entire layout `R.id.tab1`.

Add a container view in `activity_live_game_stats` xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context=".DeviceFragment" >

   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/myContainer"
    ...(Other attrs)>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and then

```
  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.myContainer, new Tab1Fragment()).commit();
    }
```

Comment: I posted an edit where I tried your method. Could you look at it and post here